# Rhapsody - imported library does not exist

Tags: java, rhapsody

I am writing a project for school in rhapsody, but I have errors saying that library does not exist. I couldn't find website to download this library, please help me. Maybe you know where download and how install this libraries.
Here's the errors:

> 1. error: package com.ibm.rational.rhapsody.animation does not exist.
> 2. error: package com.ibm.rational.rhapsody.oxf does not exist.
> 3. error: package com.ibm.rational.rhapsody.animcom does not exist.

Comment: Please consider to read the help center and update your post.

Comment: Maybe try googling the errors you are getting. From what I've seen there is some good discussion there.

Comment: I have found and read some discussion about that issue on ibm site, but there's nothing usefull. I need to find at least where to download these libraries. I have program provided by my college and i can't reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

These libraries are in the Rhapsody install folder. Try looking here:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.1.4\Share\LangJava\lib*